# Spark SQL nested withColumn

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, udf

I have a DataFrame that has multiple columns of which some of them are structs.  Something like this

```
root
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- baz: string (nullable = true)
 |-- abc: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- def: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to apply a `UserDefinedFunction` on the column `baz` to replace `baz` with a function of `baz`, but I cannot figure out how to do that.  Here is an example of the desired output (note that `baz` is now an `int`)

```
root
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- baz: int (nullable = true)
 |-- abc: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- def: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
```

It looks like `DataFrame.withColumn` only works on top level columns but not on nested columns.  I'm using Scala for this problem.

Can someone help me out with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 30):

that's easy, just use a dot to select nested structures, e.g. `$"foo.baz"` :

```
case class Foo(bar:String,baz:String)
case class Record(foo:Foo)

val df = Seq(
   Record(Foo("Hi","There"))
).toDF()


df.printSchema

root
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- baz: string (nullable = true)


val myUDF = udf((s:String) => {
 // do something with s 
  s.toUpperCase
})


df
.withColumn("udfResult",myUDF($"foo.baz"))
.show

+----------+---------+
|       foo|udfResult|
+----------+---------+
|[Hi,There]|    THERE|
+----------+---------+
```

If you want to add the result of your UDF to the existing struct `foo`, i.e. to get:

```
root
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- baz: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- udfResult: string (nullable = true)
```

there are two options:

with `withColumn`:

```
df
.withColumn("udfResult",myUDF($"foo.baz"))
.withColumn("foo",struct($"foo.*",$"udfResult"))
.drop($"udfResult")
```

with `select`:

```
df
.select(struct($"foo.*",myUDF($"foo.baz").as("udfResult")).as("foo"))
```

EDIT:
Replacing the existing attribute in the struct with the result from the UDF:
unfortunately, this does **not** work:

```
df
.withColumn("foo.baz",myUDF($"foo.baz"))
```

but can be done like this:

```
// get all columns except foo.baz
val structCols = df.select($"foo.*")
    .columns
    .filter(_!="baz")
    .map(name => col("foo."+name))

df.withColumn(
    "foo",
    struct((structCols:+myUDF($"foo.baz").as("baz")):_*)
)
```

Comment: @RaphaelRoth what are `col` and `struct` I do not find these classes in spark ?

Comment: @Gaurav Shah import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

Comment: Any idea how to get the replacement to work with the array element, so the same as above only for abc.a rather than foo.baz

Comment: Is there any solution to Breandan's question above? Thank you.

Comment: What to do if there is one more level of hierarch between foo and baz.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the `struct` function as Raphael Roth has already been demonstrated in their answer above. There is an easier way to do this though using the [Make Structs Easy](https://github.com/fqaiser94/mse)* library. The library adds a `withField` method to the Column class allowing you to add/replace Columns inside a StructType column, in much the same way as the `withColumn` method on the DataFrame class allows you to add/replace columns inside a DataFrame. For your specific use-case, you could do something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import com.github.fqaiser94.mse.methods._

// generate some fake data
case class Foo(bar: String, baz: String)
case class Record(foo: Foo, arrayOfFoo: Seq[Foo])

val df = Seq(
   Record(Foo("Hello", "World"), Seq(Foo("Blue", "Red"), Foo("Green", "Yellow")))
).toDF

df.printSchema

// root
//  |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- baz: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- arrayOfFoo: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- baz: string (nullable = true)

df.show(false)

// +--------------+------------------------------+
// |foo           |arrayOfFoo                    |
// +--------------+------------------------------+
// |[Hello, World]|[[Blue, Red], [Green, Yellow]]|
// +--------------+------------------------------+

// example user defined function that capitalizes a given string
val myUdf = udf((s: String) => s.toUpperCase)

// capitalize value of foo.baz
df.withColumn("foo", $"foo".withField("baz", myUdf($"foo.baz"))).show(false)

// +--------------+------------------------------+
// |foo           |arrayOfFoo                    |
// +--------------+------------------------------+
// |[Hello, WORLD]|[[Blue, Red], [Green, Yellow]]|
// +--------------+------------------------------+
```

I noticed you had a follow-up question about replacing a Column nested inside a struct nested inside of an array. 
This can also be done by combining the functions provided by the [Make Structs Easy](https://github.com/fqaiser94/mse/) library with the functions provided by [spark-hofs](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spark-hofs/) library, as follows:

```
import za.co.absa.spark.hofs._

// capitalize the value of foo.baz in each element of arrayOfFoo
df.withColumn("arrayOfFoo", transform($"arrayOfFoo", foo => foo.withField("baz", myUdf(foo.getField("baz"))))).show(false)

// +--------------+------------------------------+
// |foo           |arrayOfFoo                    |
// +--------------+------------------------------+
// |[Hello, World]|[[Blue, RED], [Green, YELLOW]]|
// +--------------+------------------------------+
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author of the [Make Structs Easy](https://github.com/fqaiser94/mse) library that is referenced in this answer.

Comment: Since Spark 3.1 a [withField](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html#pyspark.sql.Column.withField) method has been added to API.