# How does toDS() get injected into the Seq object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Normally in Scala if you invoke `toDS()` on a sequence, you get:

```
error: value toDS is not a member of Seq[Int]
```

However, in a SparkSession, you can invoke the same method on a Seq and it creates a DataSet.

How is this MetaProgramming actually happening?

Comment: `:imports` in scala shell vs spark-shell will show you the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from [`SparkSession.implicits`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44831789/8371915):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
```

Comment: Ok but I'm confused.  How can an import of another class effect an existing class?

Comment: @MoreThanFive Can you please share your findings if any?