# union two dataframes with nested different schemas

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Dataframe1 looks like this

```
root
 |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- results: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- content: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ptype: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- verb: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- foobar: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- fooId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = false)
 |-- hour: string (nullable = false)
```

Dataframe 2 look like below:

```
root
 |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- results: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- content: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ptype: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- verb: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- foobar: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = false)
 |-- hour: string (nullable = false)
```

Notice the differnce - there is no `fooId` in the second dataframe.
How can I union these two dataframes together? 
I understand that the two schemas need to be the same to union. What is the best way to add `fooId` or remove `fooId`?(non trivial because of the structure of the schema) What is the recommended approach for doing union of this kind. 
Thanks

Comment: To use `union` the schema of the two dataframes need to match. So either remove the `fooId` column in the first dataframe or add it (as null or any constant value) to the second dataframe.

Comment: @Shaido I have edited the question. I understand it needs to be the same.

Comment: @Shaido I want to understand how do folks handle this case without changing the inherent structure much.

Comment: To add a nested column to dataframe 2, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831789/spark-sql-nested-withcolumn. Add fooId with all null values, then you can Union the two

Comment: The above link is to add a nested column to a struct. How will you do this for arrays? it is not accessible with the `.` operator

Answer (score 0):

As you considered two Dataframes let DF1 and DF2, You could remove the extra column in the DF1 and run a untion of both the dataframes

```
// this is to remove the extra column in the dataframe
DF1.drop("fooId")
```

Now both the DFs has the same number of columns so you can do a union

```
DF1.union(DF2)
```

Comment: This will not work - as `drop` will not drop nested columns.

Answer (score 0):

try to extract all nested key-value pairs of df1 and then use drop:

```
df = df1.select(col("results.content.*"))
#this will give you all column names
#Then drop a specific column
df = df.drop("fooId")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with using `unionByName` and using `allowMissingColumns` to `True`.